# Disable a link that has href="javascript:;" until option is selected

Tags: jquery

I have a link I need to disable until a selection is made from a select box

```
<select id="shippingSelect" onchange="simpleCart.update();">
                    <option value="nothing" selected="selected">Choose Shipping Location</option>
                    <option value="uk">UK - FREE</option>
                    <option value="world">Rest of World + £2.00</option>
                </select>

<a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout"> Place Order </a>
```

How can I disable the place order link until customer chooses shipping location?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<script>
    $('#shippingSelect').change(function() {
       if ($(this).val() != "nothing") {

          $('.place_order').slideDown();
       } else {
          $('.place_order').slideUp();

       }
    });
    </script>
```

Which works but I would rather have the link visible all the time just not clickable. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your link handler you could check if something different to `nothing` was selected

```
 $('a.simpleCart_checkout').click(function(e) {
     if ($('#shippingSelect').val() == 'nothing') {
        e.preventDefault(); // disable link navigation
     }        
     // your logic for the case that something is selected
 });
```

In any case, it would be better if add some visual indication that the link is disabled like font in gray or something and you remove it when a valid element is selected on the combo box.

Another approach that take link style into account

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout disabled"> Place Order </a>
```

**CSS**

```
.disabled
{ 
    color: #AAA
}
```

​
**JS**

```
$('#shippingSelect').change(function() {
   if ($(this).val() == "nothing") {
      $('a.simpleCart_checkout').addClass('disabled');
   } 
   else {
      $('a.simpleCart_checkout').removeClass('disabled');
   }
});

$('a.simpleCart_checkout').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
       e.preventDefault(); // disable link navigation
    }        
    // your logic for the case that something is selected
});
```

**[DEMO 2nd APPROACH](http://jsfiddle.net/LtaAZ/)**

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to get this to work, do you think you could put this in a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/ Thanks!

Comment: @Anthony: Added a demo for the 2nd approach

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script to disable/enable button

```
<script>
    $('#shippingSelect').change(function() {
       if ($(this).val() != "nothing") {

          $('.place_order').removeAttr("disabled");
       } else {
          $('.place_order').attr("disabled", "disabled");

       }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It seems that the element with the class `place_order` is the hyperlink `<a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout"> Place Order </a>` (the class `place_order` has probably been forgotten). And in this case, there is no `disabled` attribute...